# Dates in columns instead of rows in SAS - advantages?

Tags: sas

Few of my clients using SAS store dates in columns.
e.g:

```
| Id | Variable1_201101 | Variable1_201102 | ... | Variable1_201909 | Variable2_201101 | Variable2_201102 | ... |
```

etc.

Instead of storing dates in rows:

```
| Id | Date | Variable1 | Variable2 |
```

In a result, they have huge number of cells, because even if some ID does not exist in particular date, there will be empty cell in first structure, where in second structure, the row will be omitted.

I have never met such storage structures in SQL, where it wouldn't be perfect solution. Are there any advantages of such structures in SAS?

Comment: The only advantage is that some statisticians are to dumb to handle it when not everything is in one row per id (maybe patient, customer or whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never a perfect storage structure.  There are superior structures for solutions to problems at hand.  Sometimes you have to reshape data for a particular solution, sometimes a procedure has grammar or mechanisms for reshaping within the procedure itself.

For example, examining a variable in different time frames in `The TTEST Procedure` might use a `PAIRED` statement and require different variables for the values.  Thus the comparing Jan-2011 values to Jan-2012 values would make sense to have structure with `Variable1_201101`  `Variable1_201201`.

Disk space for sparse wide data can be reduced effectively using `COMPRESS=` options, at the cost of decompression CPU cycles.  Depending on the data it can be significantly less disk use, but then is hard to deal with in alternate categorical analysis.

Traditional RDBMS has the categorical form (vertical) as a very common best practice, with indexing and foreign keys.  If this is the original layout, you might need to pivot or reshape the data for a particular TTEST analysis.

Dealing with data found in a NOSQL data store you might end up more often encountering the horizontal form (because underlayment handles sparseness better).

Comment: To conclude: the higher disk space usage caused by empty cells (if ID does not exist for particular date) might be reduced by using `COMPRESS=`. However this requires decompression during reading the dataset. The horizontal structure might be only helpful for some procedures.

Comment: That is an accurate conclusion.  I did not have enough time to write such a short answer.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare code:

```
data have;
id=786;
Variable1_201101 = 78; 
Variable1_201102  =67;  
Variable1_201909 = 23; 
Variable2_201101 = 34 ;
Variable2_201102  = 12;
run;
```

Now, we have :

```
+-----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| id  | Variable1_201101 | Variable1_201102 | Variable1_201909 | Variable2_201101 | Variable2_201102 |
+-----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 786 |               78 |               67 |               23 |               34 |               12 |
+-----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Use transpose with wildcards:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=have
    OUT=have2
    PREFIX=Column
    NAME=Source
    LABEL=Label
;
    BY id;
    VAR Variable1_: Variable2_:;
```

Result:

```
+-----+------------------+---------+
| id  |      Source      | Column1 |
+-----+------------------+---------+
| 786 | Variable1_201101 |      78 |
| 786 | Variable1_201102 |      67 |
| 786 | Variable1_201909 |      23 |
| 786 | Variable2_201101 |      34 |
| 786 | Variable2_201102 |      12 |
+-----+------------------+---------+
```

Now we will be "parse":

```
    data have3;
    set have2;
    format date ddmmyyp10.; 
    date_str=substr(Source,find(source,"_")+1);
    date=INputN(date_str||"01"," yymmn6.");
    variable_name=substr(Source,1,find(source,"_")-1);


/*  Optional*/
drop date_str source ;
    run;

    PROC SORT
    ;
    BY date id;
RUN;
```

And transpose again:

```
    PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=have3
    OUT=want (drop=source)
    PREFIX=Column
    NAME=Source
    LABEL=Label
;
    BY date id;
    ID variable_name;
    VAR Column1;
```

Result:

```
+------------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+
|    date    | id  | ColumnVariable1 | ColumnVariable2 |
+------------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+
| 01.01.2011 | 786 |              78 |              34 |
| 01.02.2011 | 786 |              67 |              12 |
| 01.09.2019 | 786 |              23 |               . |
+------------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: It's not the answer to my question. I was asking about advantages in terms of performance and efficient of such structures, where dates are distributed for each variable. If there are no advantages, I will transpose it.